# Create ISO from directory, but only one filetype

Tags: iso

Say I have a directory structured as follows:

- Directory

  - Subdirectory 1

    - file.png
    - file.jpg
  - Subdirectory 2

    - file.png
    - file.jpg

I'd like to burn this to an ISO, but only the .jpg's. I want to preserve the directory structure, though, so that the ISO would look like this:

- Directory

  - Subdirectory 1

    - file.jpg
  - Subdirectory 2

    - file.jpg

Without copying the whole top-level directory and deleting the things I don't want. I've been reading about "genisoimage" (http://www.tuxarena.com/static/tut_iso_cli.php), but I don't see any built-in mechanism for filtering based on filetype or file name. Is there a way to achieve this with either this tool or another tool, or perhaps combining a tool like grep and piping the output in to genisoimage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mkisofs`.

Execute this command in `Directory` if you want to keep empty directories:

```
mkisofs -o out.iso -find -name '*.jpg' -o -type d
```

Execute this command in `Directory` if you don't want to keep empty directories:

```
mkisofs -o out.iso -find -name '*.jpg'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The removal of empty directories is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `man genisoimage` you'll find the `-m` option which takes a "glob" pattern of filenames to exclude, so in your case add the arguments `-m '*.png'`.

Comment: `genisoimage` is an unmaintained fork from a `mkisofs` version from 2004. You don't like to use it as it creates filesystems with defects that may not be accepted by all filesystem implementations in operating systems. The original software fixed aprox. 50 bugs in 2005 and 2006 that are still present in the fork.

Comment: Thanks @schily. To find genisoimage, I Googled "Linux make ISO command line", and got this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90793/create-iso-image-from-folder-via-terminal-commands. The top-rated answer with 16 votes is about genisoimage, but the answer with 0 votes is about mkisofs

Comment: This is sad news, but well known. There are people who like to attack OpenSource and these people try to advertize for `genisoimage` even though they never would use a 12 year old Linux kernel today.